# Using TIdTCPServer to AS400

Tags: delphi, ssl, delphi-xe2, indy

I have a small "testing" program in Delphi XE2. I want to use this to test the SSL connection from the AS400 to the IDTCPServer.
The As400 creates then connects a socket on port 992 (SSL Telnet) to which the server is bound.

I have created a SSL certificate using OpenSSL as per 
http://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/12/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl/
and successfully imported this to the AS400.
I can see the AS400 job is connected to port 992 on the AS400. Wireshark indicates port 992 is allocated on the PC running the server; but when the AS400 send the `SSL_HANDSHAKE` it times out due to no reply. I have set the timeout to 1 min, but if i put it to no limit, there is no reply after 20 mins.
The IDTCPServer uses `TiDServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL`

procedure `prc_SetUpSSL` is activated prior t trying to send the message from the AS400

```
procedure TUDPMainForm.prc_SetupSSL;
var
  CurrDirectory : string;
  RetLength : integer;
begin
  SetLength(CurrDirectory, 255);
  RetLength := GetCurrentDirectory(255, PChar(CurrDirectory));
  SetLength(CurrDirectory, RetLength);

  SSL_Server.Bindings.Add.Port := StrToInt(edt_Port.Text);
  SSL_Handler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := CurrDirectory + '\ia.key';
  SSL_Handler.SSLOptions.CertFile := CurrDirectory + '\ia.crt';
  SSL_Handler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := CurrDirectory + '\ia.crt';

  SSL_Server.Active := True;
end;
```

The server is active as the OnExecute event is triggered when the AS400 connects to the socket. I get a "Connected xxx" message.

```
procedure TUDPMainForm.SSL_ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  a : array[0..3000] of byte;
  s: string;
begin
    //Receives the message from the client
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    SetString(s, PAnsiChar(@a[0]), Length(a));
    while (StrPos(Pchar(s), Pchar('  ')) <> nil)  do
        s:= StringReplace(s,'  ',' ', [rfReplaceAll]);

    if s <> '' then
        begin
          UDPMemo.Lines.Add('Connected : ' + DateTimeToStr(Now));
          UDPMemo.Lines.Add(s);
        end;

end;
```

Any help on this would be very appreciated i am going round in circles and getting no where.
Thanks,
Geoff Cox

Comment: Have you tried to connect from a different system with a telnet-ssl client?

Comment: `when the AS400 send the SSL_HANDSHAKE it times out due to no reply` - then it is very unlikely that the SSL_ServerExecute method will execute. Do you also see the line in the Memo which is generated by `UDPMemo.Lines.Add(s)` following the `Connected xxx` ?

Comment: The OnExecute event is fired when the socket from the AS400 is created and connects to the Indy server. This shows that the port is open and active. It is the IOHandler which does not reply i assume(?)
I will try and set up a SSL-Telnet session and try to see if it can communicate with the server instance.
The value of s appears to be gibberish and indeed nothing is written to UDPMemo